# Using Data from a Table Relationship

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Hello All I am a fairly new user to Access 2010 and I have a question relating to using the data from a table relationship. I am creating a database that has a tblUser and tblQA. tblUser stores their FullName, UserName, and Team. tblQA includes the UserName as well many other fields related to individual Quality Assessments. I want to be able to view quality assessments by team as well as single user and I think that proper database design would be to use the relationship rather than to capture the team as a separate field in my tblQA. Here is where I run into trouble- how do I create a query of tblQA that is filtered by the team field of tblUser? Here is the Relationship table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUKl6.jpg Let me know if I can provide any other info. Its a bit hard to know what all I need to provide even after reading the clear questions section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have the relationships done more or less.

It's not perfect (for example you use the field name **Team** in two tables, in **tblUser** it contains an ID, and in **tblTeams** it contains a team name I presume) - but it should work.

Now you need to create a query, add the tables that interest you to it, the joins should appear automatically. And then you pull the fields you need (to see and/or set conditions against) from the tables to the field list at the bottom (for joined fields you only need one of the pair), and set conditions that suit your needs, for example `UserLogin` would have a condition `="jsmith"` or `Team` `= "Sales"`. Run the query and you'll see 1 or more rows with data from all 3 tables.

And you go from there (probably substituting literal conditions like `= "jsmith` with a variable set by a form or VBA.

If it's not what you need - please comment.

Comment: Sorry yes the tblQA includes a team field but I'm now told that bad design. Based on your info I was able to create a new query (and related form) based on the relationship. Thank you!